# PDO error message 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble getting this to work I will include the code both working and what I am trying to accomplish. In the first code it is non-working and gives me an error message: `Connection failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':userName AND`password`=:userPass' at line 1`
I have tried several different combinations of syntax and still no luck. In the second code example it is working code and basically I am trying to get rid of all the unnecessary code to just obtain a `$row` count from the function to verify that there was 1 row that matched the query.

```
function checkLogin($conn,$myusername, $mypassword) {

       $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `CLL_users` WHERE `user_name`= :userName AND `password`= :userPass');
       $stmt->bindValue(':userName', $myusername);
       $stmt->bindValue(':userPass', $mypassword);
       $stmt->execute();
       $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
       return $count;
}
```

Comment: If you use named parameters, you have to call [`PDO::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) instead of `PDO::query`. Like: `$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \`CLL_users\`...');` - And `$results = $conn->query($sql);` should be `$sql->execute()`.

Comment: @vstm I have tried that and it will just give me a blank page with no error message...

Comment: Well you have to also replace `$count = $results->fetchColumn();` with `$count = $sql->fetchColumn();`. Plus you should configure your PHP to display all errors while developing, so it shows what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I was able to get ride of the error message with your suggestion but it will not output the value of the variable when i try to echo it

Comment: Can you update your question so that we see how the code looks like now?

Comment: I updated the code and got it working the reflected code in the question is now working code except for one thing. I cannot pass the variable `$count` into the file im calling it from I can echo it fine in the function to print to the screen but when I try to echo from the file I get nothing....

Comment: I think you need to add a [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)-statement to the function. You can add `return $count;` before the closing brace of the function.

Comment: You are right I posted another question about that issue and was answered with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkLogin($conn,$myusername, $mypassword) {

           $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `CLL_users` WHERE `user_name`= :userName AND `password`= :userPass');
           $stmt->bindValue(':userName', $myusername);
           $stmt->bindValue(':userPass', $mypassword);
           $stmt->execute();
           $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
           return $count;
    }
```